# Can you cross pipes in SpaceChem?

Tags: spacechem

Is there anyway to have one pipe go over or under another, so as to avoid having to make long round-a-bout journeys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pipes can cross at right angles, just drag the path of one over others.  They cannot turn while crossing over others though, so there must be a free space after the crossing.

In the below exaggerated mess, the bottom end, for example, cannot go to where the cursor is without some ripping up of the existing pipes.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't working for me before. I must have been trying to cross over a stair case shaped pipe. I'm too tired for this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget, a track cannot cross itself, regardless of what angle they meet at.